# Can I use 'hang out' with an adverb like 'happily', 'nicely'?

Tags: word-usage, adverbs

In this case, I took the following meaning..
To hang out means to spend a lot of time in a place.

Now, I would like to know-
Can I use an adverb like 'happily', 'nicely' with the slang 'hang out'?

It could go like this:
I hung out happily with my friends.
How happily/nicely I used to hang out back in the day!

Are they correct?

Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no grammar rule that says that you can't.

"I hung out happily"  is just fine.  It means that you were happy while you hung out with your friends

"I hung out nicely" is slightly odd - what do you mean by "nice"?  Does it mean that you were pleasant, neat, and virtuous?

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, by 'nicely' I wanted to mean the same meaning as 'happily'. And now I can say 'How happily I used to hang out back in the day!' is a correct one, can't I?